# Unable to generate java code for webservice using WSDLToJava with Apache CXF 3.1.6

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, wsdl2java

I am trying to generate the java code for webservice using `WSDLToJava` in Apache CXF 3.1.6, but I am getting this exception and I don't know from where the Velocity templates are coming into picture.

```
WSDLToJava Error: Could not find Velocity template file: org/apache/cxf/tools/wsdlto/frontend/jaxws/template/service.vm
```

I was trying to locate the file in my project or in the generated code, but I don't see it anywhere.

Do I need to include the velocity jars in my project or do I need to create a `service.vm` velocity template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `service.vm` file is part `cxf-tools-wsdlto-frontend-jaxws.jar`, make sure its part of lib directory when running Wsdl2Java command. I would recommand you to use all the jars present as part of cxf binary distribution shown below or use any build script such as maven and use cxf-codegen-maven plugin such the it resolves jar dependencies and downloads automatically.

[image]

Comment: Yep. That did it. I am still wondering why it didn't work, when I had the jar file on my classpath. But when I added them all, the error wasn't there. Strange though.